# MassTransit messages types must not be System types exception

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'm pretty new to MassTransit and don't understand what am I doing wrong to get the following exception: `Messages types must not be System types`.

Here are my definitions:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class ArcProcess : SagaStateMachineInstance, ISagaVersion
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }

    public string CurrentState { get; set; }

    public int Version { get; set; }

    public Guid ActivationId { get; set; }
}

public static class MessageContracts
{
    static bool _initialized;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        if (_initialized)
            return;

        GlobalTopology.Send.UseCorrelationId<StartProcessingMessage>(x => x.ActivationId);
        GlobalTopology.Send.UseCorrelationId<ReconstructionFinishedMessage>(x => x.ActivationId);
        GlobalTopology.Send.UseCorrelationId<ProcessingFinishedMessage>(x => x.ActivationId);

        _initialized = true;
    }
}
```

2 of my consumers are:

```
public class StartReconstructionConsumer : IConsumer<StartProcessingMessage>
{
    readonly ILogger<StartReconstructionConsumer> _Logger;

    private readonly int _DelaySeconds = 5;

    public StartReconstructionConsumer(ILogger<StartReconstructionConsumer> logger)
    {
        _Logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<StartProcessingMessage> context)
    {
        var activationId = context.Message.ActivationId;

        _Logger.LogInformation($"Received Scan: {activationId}");

        await Task.Delay(_DelaySeconds * 1000);

        _Logger.LogInformation($"Finish Scan: {activationId}");

        await context.Publish<ReconstructionFinishedMessage>(new { ActivationId = activationId });
    }
}

public class ProcessingFinishedConsumer : IConsumer<ProcessingFinishedMessage>
{
    readonly ILogger<ProcessingFinishedConsumer> _Logger;

    public ProcessingFinishedConsumer(ILogger<ProcessingFinishedConsumer> logger)
    {
        _Logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ProcessingFinishedMessage> context)
    {
        _Logger.LogInformation($"Finish {context.Message.ActivationId}");

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And here is the StateMachine definition:

```
public class ArcStateMachine: MassTransitStateMachine<ArcProcess>
{
    static ArcStateMachine()
    {
        MessageContracts.Initialize();
    }

    public ArcStateMachine()
    {
        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

        Initially(
            When(ProcessingStartedEvent)
            .Then(context =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">> ProcessingStartedEvent");
                context.Instance.ActivationId = context.Data.ActivationId;
            })
            .TransitionTo(ProcessingStartedState));

        During(ProcessingStartedState,
            When(ReconstructionFinishedEvent)
            .Then(context =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">> ReconstructionFinishedEvent");
                context.Instance.ActivationId = context.Data.ActivationId;
            })
            .Publish(context =>
            {
                return context.Init<ProcessingFinishedMessage>(new { ActivationId = context.Data.ActivationId });
            })
            .TransitionTo(ProcessingFinishedState)
            .Finalize());
    }

    public State ProcessingStartedState { get; }
    public State ReconstructionStartedState { get; }
    public State ReconstructionFinishedState { get; }
    public State ProcessingFinishedState { get; }

    public Event<StartProcessingMessage> ProcessingStartedEvent { get; }
    public Event<ReconstructionStartedMessage> ReconstructionStartedEvent { get; }
    public Event<ReconstructionFinishedMessage> ReconstructionFinishedEvent { get; }
    public Event<ProcessingFinishedMessage> ProcessingFinishedEvent { get; }
}
```

And the setup for MassTransit looks the following:

```
var rabbitHost = Configuration["RABBIT_MQ_HOST"];

        if (rabbitHost.IsNotEmpty())
        {
            services.AddMassTransit(cnf =>
            {
                var connectionString = Configuration["MONGO_DB_CONNECTION_STRING"];

                var machine = new ArcStateMachine();
                var repository = MongoDbSagaRepository<ArcProcess>.Create(connectionString,
                    "mongoRepo", "WorkflowState");

                cnf.AddConsumer(typeof(StartReconstructionConsumer));
                cnf.AddConsumer(typeof(ProcessingFinishedConsumer));

                cnf.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host(new Uri(rabbitHost), hst =>
                    {
                        hst.Username("guest");
                        hst.Password("guest");
                    });

                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(BusConstants.SagaQueue,
                        e => e.StateMachineSaga(machine, repository));
                });
            });

            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyApp", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
```

I have several questions about it:

1. When actually the event is published as a result of publishing a message? I.e. in my example `await _BusInstance.Bus.Publish<StartProcessingMessage>(new { ActivationId = id });` is called from a WebApi which is consumed by `StartReconstructionConsumer` but when actually the state machine starts to act with `Initially(When(ProcessingStartedEvent)...`?
2. My processing should ensure I'm already in the `ProcessingStartedState` state in order to `During(ProcessingStartedState, When(ReconstructionFinishedEvent)...` to act correctly. So how do I ensure that my consumer that fires upon receive of `StartProcessingMessage` can publish the `ReconstructionFinishedMessage` that should initiate that `During`? Am I building the messages exchange correctly?
3. Currently for the `await context.Publish<ReconstructionFinishedMessage>(new { ActivationId = activationId });` I get an exception in the logs that states `R-FAULT rabbitmq://localhost/saga.service d4070000-7b3b-704d-0f10-08d99942c959 Nanox.GC.Shared.AppCore.Messages.ReconstructionFinishedMessage ReconCaller.Saga.ArcProcess(00:00:04.1132604)` while that guid in the message is actually the `MessageId`. And my message in the rabbitmq is routed to `saga.service_error` with an exception `Messages types must not be System types: System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Nanox.GC.Shared.AppCore.Messages.ProcessingFinishedMessage> (Parameter 'T')`.

It seems like I'm missing here really big..

My intent is to initiate processing that will have several stages processed by a few consumers sequentially. So here I tried to build a simple StateMachine that starts whenever someone called `StartProcessing`, then each consumer will do its job and fire the `FinishedStepX` which will promote the state machine to a new step and initiate the next consumer up until all the processing is done and the state machine will report `ProcessingComplete`.

Thanks for any help n advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your bus configuration is a bit strange, so I've cleaned that up:

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(cnf =>
{
    var connectionString = Configuration["MONGO_DB_CONNECTION_STRING"];

    cfg.AddSagaStateMachine<ArcStateMachine, ArcProcess>()
        .Endpoint(e => e.Name = BusConstants.SagaQueue)
        .MongoDbRepository(connectionString, r =>
        {
            r.DatabaseName = "mongoRepo";
            r.CollectionName = "WorkflowState";
        });

    cnf.AddConsumer<StartReconstructionConsumer>();
    cnf.AddConsumer<ProcessingFinishedConsumer>();

    cnf.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(new Uri(rabbitHost), hst =>
        {
            hst.Username("guest");
            hst.Password("guest");
        });

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
```

And the publish issue is related to the method being used, only *PublishAsync* allows the use of message initializers:

```cs
During(ProcessingStartedState,
    When(ReconstructionFinishedEvent)
        .Then(context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(">> ReconstructionFinishedEvent");
            context.Instance.ActivationId = context.Data.ActivationId;
        })
        .PublishAsync(context =>
        {
            return context.Init<ProcessingFinishedMessage>(new { ActivationId = context.Data.ActivationId });
        })
        .TransitionTo(ProcessingFinishedState)
        .Finalize());
```

That should sort you out.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response (small fix: `cnf.AddSaga..`). Fixed the issue. Now something new: upon publishing the `ProcessingFinishedMessage` I receive in the logs: `R-FAULT rabbitmq://localhost/saga.service d4070000-7b3b-704d-e7df-08d9994b2062 Nanox.GC.Shared.AppCore.Messages.ProcessingFinishedMessage ReconCaller.Saga.ArcProcess(00:00:00.0286223)` and the message goes to `saga.service_error` with the following error message: `The ProcessingFinishedEvent event is not handled during the ProcessingStartedState state for the ArcStateMachine state machine`. Should I add some `.Ignore()` for this?

Comment: Why would you handle processing finished in your state machine anyway? Isn't it just producing the event? Remove it from the state machine, and you'll likely have to delete the exchange bindings in RMQ.

Comment: Then how does the system know that processing has completed all of the stages? This is why I have the `ProcessingFinishedConsumer` that should update the system/the user (whatsoever) that the processing has successfully passed all the stages. And I also would like the state machine to update the state to `ProcessingFinishedState` so it will be reflected in the messages repo. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, calling `Finalize` transitions to `Final`. If you want the state machine to remain ing the `ProcessingFinishedState` don't call `Finalize`. There is no reason to consume the event to change the state, it's producing the event – it already knows.

Comment: In regard to calling `Finalize` I understood. So alternatively I can just get rid of the `ProcessingFinishedState` so I just removed the `.TransitionTo(ProcessingFinishedState)` and use only `.Finalize());` but I still get the same error in the RMQ because of (I suppose) publishing the `ProcessingFinishedMessage` [prior to finalization] which is consumed by `ProcessingFinishedConsumer` which I do need so my system understands when the state machine has completed. Should I implement it differently?

Answer (score 1):

With the generous help of @Chris Patterson the working solution would be:

Definitions:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class ArcProcess : SagaStateMachineInstance, ISagaVersion
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }

    public string CurrentState { get; set; }

    public int Version { get; set; }

    public Guid ActivationId { get; set; }
}

public interface StartProcessingMessage
{
    Guid ActivationId { get; }
}

public interface ProcessingFinishedMessage
{
    Guid ActivationId { get; }
}

public static class MessageContracts
{
    static bool _initialized;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        if (_initialized)
            return;

        GlobalTopology.Send.UseCorrelationId<StartProcessingMessage>(x => x.ActivationId);
        GlobalTopology.Send.UseCorrelationId<ProcessingFinishedMessage>(x => x.ActivationId);

        _initialized = true;
    }
}
```

Consumers:

```
public class StartProcessingConsumer : IConsumer<StartProcessingMessage>
{
    readonly ILogger<StartProcessingConsumer> _Logger;

    private readonly int _DelaySeconds = 5;

    public StartProcessingConsumer(ILogger<StartProcessingConsumer> logger)
    {
        _Logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<StartProcessingMessage> context)
    {
        var activationId = context.Message.ActivationId;

        _Logger.LogInformation($"Received Scan: {activationId}");

        await Task.Delay(_DelaySeconds * 1000);

        _Logger.LogInformation($"Finish Scan: {activationId}");

        await context.Publish<ProcessingFinishedMessage>(new { ActivationId = activationId });
    }
}

public class ProcessingFinishedConsumer : IConsumer<ProcessingFinishedMessage>
{
    readonly ILogger<ProcessingFinishedConsumer> _Logger;

    public ProcessingFinishedConsumer(ILogger<ProcessingFinishedConsumer> logger)
    {
        _Logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ProcessingFinishedMessage> context)
    {
        _Logger.LogInformation($"Finish {context.Message.ActivationId}");

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

StateMachine definition:

```
public class ArcStateMachine: MassTransitStateMachine<ArcProcess>
{
    static ArcStateMachine()
    {
        MessageContracts.Initialize();
    }

    public ArcStateMachine()
    {
        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

        Initially(
            When(ProcessingStartedEvent)
            .Then(context =>
            {
                context.Instance.ActivationId = context.Data.ActivationId;
            })
            .TransitionTo(ProcessingStartedState));

        During(ProcessingStartedState,
            When(ProcessingFinishedEvent)
            .Then(context =>
            {
                context.Instance.ActivationId = context.Data.ActivationId;
            })
            .Finalize());
    }

    public State ProcessingStartedState { get; }
    public State ProcessingFinishedState { get; }

    public Event<StartProcessingMessage> ProcessingStartedEvent { get; }
    public Event<ProcessingFinishedMessage> ProcessingFinishedEvent { get; }
}
```

MassTransit setup:

```
var rabbitHost = Configuration["RABBIT_MQ_HOST"];

        if (rabbitHost.IsNotEmpty())
        {
            services.AddMassTransit(cnf =>
            {
                var connectionString = Configuration["MONGO_DB_CONNECTION_STRING"];

                cnf.AddSagaStateMachine<ArcStateMachine, ArcProcess>()
                    .Endpoint(e => e.Name = BusConstants.SagaQueue)
                    .MongoDbRepository(connectionString, r =>
                    {
                        r.DatabaseName = "mongoRepo";
                        r.CollectionName = "WorkflowState";
                    });


                cnf.AddConsumer(typeof(StartProcessingConsumer));
                cnf.AddConsumer(typeof(ProcessingFinishedConsumer));

                cnf.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host(new Uri(rabbitHost), hst =>
                    {
                        hst.Username("guest");
                        hst.Password("guest");
                    });

                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });
            });

            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyApp", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
```

This example helped me a lot in understanding how the basics of MassTrasit work.

Comment: Thanks for showing your final work. So all is good at this point?

Comment: Yes, it's perfect. I have also added an intermediate stage to check 2 stages execution and it works fine. My current task is to find a way in which I'm treating any Exception that may occur in consumers. The outcome I receive is that [queue_name]_error is created and the message appears there. I've added a Fault<> consumer but now I have 2 issues: a) how can I make this consumer treat any Fault of any Message type?; b) make the message disappear from the _error queue upon its treatment by the Fault consumer?

Comment: The `Fault<T>` published by a failing consumer is separate from the original message which is moved to the *_error* queue. Management of the error queue is a separate concern, not handled by MassTransit.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My question is whether there is a way to still have `Fault<>` consumers to deal with any type of the fault/exception in the code that consumes messages, but prevent messages be routed to the `_error` queue(s)?

Comment: You can specify `DiscardFaultedMessages()` on the receive endpoint configuration, but proceed with caution since faulted messages will be lost.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. The question then is how do I configure `DiscardFaultedMessages()` with the configuration setup I have in my project? Could you please guide me what should I change in my `services.AddMassTransit(...)` as it is coded in this thread?

Comment: Use a [consumer definition](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/definitions.html) or `AddConfigureEndpointsCallback`.

Comment: Oh, that's cool. I've used the `ConsumerDefinition<>` to declare the `DiscardFaultedMessages()` and it worked like a charm. Currently I ran into a new issue with the state machine but I'll post a new thread for that and whenever everything will play perfectly will post here a full solution with `Fault<>` consumer and `ConsumerDefinition<>` to have a fully working orchestrator for fully decoupled services.